# asynch socket listener receiving data very late for some clients

Tags: c#, serversocket

I am making a server socket in c# with async method. Here is the code I am using....

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Currently there are more than 200 clients connected at a time (can be more than 1000 at a time). Connected clients are just sending data (no need to send back messages by server).

Problem: Socket is receiving data often late (1-10 hrs late) from some clients.

What should be changed in the code to resolve the issue.

My actual code is below...

```
public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public static void StartListening()
    {
        IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[0], GlobalVariable.ListenPort);
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        try
        {

            listener.Bind((EndPoint)ipEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(GlobalVariable.MaxConnectionBacklog);
            while (true)
            {
                allDone.Reset();
                //Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
                allDone.WaitOne();     
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {

            allDone.Set();
            Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = ((Socket)ar.AsyncState).EndAccept(ar);

            StateObject stateObject = new StateObject();
            stateObject.workSocket = handler;


            listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        string content="";
        try
        {
            string str = string.Empty;
            StateObject stateObject = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = stateObject.workSocket;


            int count = handler.EndReceive(ar);
            if (count <= 0)
                return;

            stateObject.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(stateObject.buffer, 0, count));

            stateObject.sb.Clear();





             if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
             {
               // processing data with db insertion.

             }
             else
             {
                handler.BeginReceive(stateObject.buffer, 0,stateObject.buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), stateObject);
             }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {}
    }
```

Comment: 1 - 10 hours late?  Well we can eliminate a connection issue because `TCP` requires an `ACK` when sending messages.  There's likely a multi-threading bug somewhere in your code.  Either the client isn't sending the message when you think it is or the server is sitting on it for some reason.  I suppose it's possible the thread pool is extremely starved but that long of a delay is wild.  Try posting both server and client code.

Comment: why 2times `BeginAccept`? At least put in some loggin into the *catch-alls* - and btw: add logging (with timestamps) this should give you some clues. Where is the Client-Code?

Comment: @CarstenKönig Somewhere on a blog there was a suggestion to use the "begin accept"  for multiple client concurrently. However I was not sure but I tried it. I am logging the errors in a text file in exception and it's not giving any clue. Client is a embedded device which is sending data on a port every 30 seconds and I don't have client code.

Comment: If you remove the `ManualResetEvent` and use a `TcpListener` you will get this anyway (highly recommened imho)

Comment: thank u @CarstenKönig. I'll try this and will update in case any problem.